# Is this behavior due to possible async?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

Salutations,

I am fairly new to C#, I feel comfortable with Java, and thus I feel decently comfortable with C# (massive fan of its LINQ and SQL syntax). Anywho, I am however a total novice to asynchronous calls, and I was wondering if the following behavior is related to this.

So in my code I have the following:

```
    string sentence;


    Console.WriteLine("Enter your sentence: {0}", sentence = Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Sentence is: {0}", sentence);

    Console.ReadKey();
```

It is very simple, I was just trying to see if I could insert the reading of the input within the same prompt that asks for it. However, what I notice is that the code runs, but it is a blank screen, I can type my input and then it would display what I typed, and wait for a key click in order to close the CMD window.

What I was wondering is the following: Is this a sort of async behavior -- if not, what is it then? And if so, is it possible to have the ReadLine() within the same Console.WriteLine() or do I have to have them as two separate lines as one would normally do?

Comment: your command is `Console.WriteLine("string")` which contains an inner `Console.ReadLine()`, which means in order for your `WriteLine` to execute, your program first needs to execute the `ReadLine` to then be able to Execute the `Writeline` command. so that is why... so No, its not related to `Async`, its Rather the Order of Execution of methods of the application.

Comment: Mm, a downvote, eh, I suppose asking newbish questions is frowned upon in SO. Eh, CS folk were never known to have people skills.

Comment: i suggest you read this book , it contains some interesting information https://www.amazon.com/Exam-Ref-70-483-Programming-MCSD/dp/0735676828

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing about asynchronous here.

The first `Console.WriteLine` requires its parameter(s) to get ready before its own execution. In other words, `Console.ReadLine` has to execute before the first `Console.WriteLine`. That is where the blank screen come from.

Just write as

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter your sentence: ");
sentence = Console.ReadLine()
Console.WriteLine("Sentence is: {0}", sentence);
```

or in "the same line"

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter your sentence: ");
Console.WriteLine("Sentence is: {0}", Console.ReadLine());
```

Comment: Gotcha, was thinking along those lines too. I was reading a bit about async so that is why I had this on my mind. Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Synchronous and Asynchronous is not the concern here, just syntax error try

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter your sentence: ");
Console.WriteLine("Sentence is: {0}", Console.ReadLine());
```